# Travelling from India to Hawaii

Tags: visas, transit, thailand, indian-citizens, south-korea

I am planning to travel from Chennai (India) to Honolulu (Hawaii). I have the option to travel through Bangkok, Thailand and Seoul, South Korea, and want to know if either of these places will require a transit visa.

Comment: So what is your question? Do you need a transit visa to pass through Thailand or South Korea? If that is your question, you should ask just that.

Comment: Yes, that is my exact question: Do I need a transit visa to pass through Thailand or South Korea while travelling from India to Hawaii?
Sorry for the mess up.

Comment: I have edited your question to ask this question, then. Can you tell us your citizenship?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rome2rio presents [some possible routings](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Chennai/Honolulu), which go via Bangkok, Kuala Lumpur or Hong Kong (1st stop) and Japan (2nd stop).  Any of these would be a good choice for you, since none of these countries require visas for a same-day, same-airport transfer.

Going via the mainland US makes no sense, it's a long detour in the wrong direction.